# Interpreting Estimated Coefficients of Linear Regression

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, interpretation

I have data that requires interpretation of the below coefficients.

Description of variables: "`region`" = the beneficiary’s residential area in the US;
a factor with levels `northeast`, `southeast`, `southwest`, `northwest`.
"`charges`"= individual medical costs billed by health insurance for a year in dollars.

```
ml<-lm(charges~region)

Coefficients:
                Estimate   
(Intercept)      13406.4      
regionnorthwest   -988.8         
regionsoutheast   1329.0         
regionsouthwest  -1059.4
```

My interpretation is:

$b0=13406.4$

When the beneficiary's residential area is 0 or located in no region of the US, 13406.4 is the cost of medical charges in dollars.

$b1=-988.8$ (regionnorthwest is 1, others are 0)

For each increase of 1 region or if the beneficiary is living in the northwest region of the US, considering charges, there's a decrease of 988.8 dollars.

$b1=1329.0$ (regionsoutheast is 1, others are 0)

For each increase of 1 region or if the beneficiary is living in the southeast region of the US, there's an increase of 1329 dollars in medical charges.

$b1=-1054.4$ (regionsouthwest is 1, others are 0)

For each increase of 1 region or if the beneficiary is living in the southwest region of the US, there's a decrease by 1054.4 dollars in case of charges.

Is there any other way to interpret them?

Comment: The intercept is the cost of the first factor, In this case the northeast.  The rest of the interpretation is fine.

Comment: If your training data comprises only US residents then you should not interpret it for people "located in no region of the US". The Estimate of $13406$ is for all those who were in the training data and who are not one of the other group. Each in the other groups are $13406 + bx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note here that the reference category for the region variable is `northeast`.

Therefore, assuming that you are using the default contrast coding:

> ```
> (Intercept)      13406.4
> ```

means that the outcome has an expected value of 13406.4 for the northeast region.

> ```
> regionnorthwest   -988.8
> ```

means that the northwest region has an expected value for charges of   988.8 less than that of the northeast region

> ```
> regionsoutheast   1329.0
> ```

means that the southeast region has an expected value for charges of 1329 more than that of the northeast region

> ```
> regionsouthwest  -1059.4
> ```

means that the southwest region has an expected value for charges of 1059.4 less than that of the northeast region